# SSAS 2005 MDX long running Query Failure error - The Operation Has been cancelled

Tags: ssas

can you please help me in solving above mentioned error. I am new to SSAS and seeking your expertise here.

MDX query runs for a longer time (30 minutes) & throws error - Server : The Operations has been cancelled.

can you please guide me in retrieving complete error details? which log file stores error description? how to read it?

please help me in resolving this issue? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: From which environment are you running the query? From SQL Server management Studio? From your custom application? If so, how are you calling the statement?

Comment: Hi. I am trying to run this statement from Management Studio. now I am getting following error when ran the query

Memory error: Allocation failure : Not enough storage is available to process this command. .